# Script en Google Sheets para "Refrescar" las formulas de un gran rango de celdas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Me gustaría que me ayudéis a encontrar un script par Google Sheets, que al ejecutarla refresque las formulas  de un gran rango de celdas (Unas 100.000). Actualmente las formulas se activan al pulsar ENTER encima....y claro no puedo hacerlo 100.000 veces. He visto que en excel se puede hacer pero no he encontrado nada para Hoja de calculo de Google.

Comment: Indica que has intentado o que codigo has picado.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor agrega una breve descripción de tus esfuerzos de búsqueda/investigación como se sugiere en [ask].

Comment: ¿A qué te estás refiriendo con que "*se activan al pulsar enter*"? Si cada celda tiene una fórmula y se cambia una celda a la que están haciendo referencia, todas las 100.000 celdas con fórmula se van a actualizar... La verdad no te entiendo, ¿cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Hola, gracias por interesarte. Las formulas hacen referencia a celdas de hojas que aun no existen. En el momento que me veo en la necesidad de crear una hoja la formula no extrae la informacion de esta hasta que pulso enter en la celda y son muchisimas celdas...Necesitaria una script que actualice todas las formulas para evitar esta labor. Mil gracias Pollo.

Comment: Entiendo la pregunta de Ruben creo, lo que trata de explicar es que dos libros que estan conectados, uno con una formula y otro sin formula no refresca dicha informacion.
La macro de refrescar el libro seria la mejor opcion en vez de estar abriendo el libro a cada cambio que realizamos. Yo quiero intentar lo mismo pero aun no lo he logrado.